# Laravel Fix No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, laravel, xmlhttprequest, cors

How to solve

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

On Laravel 7

what can I do to the response?

I have tried this, but it doens't include the header.

```
return response()->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')->json([
            'error'=>false,
        ]);
```

## Edit 1

I already have FruitCakes Cors added (https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

My xhr request is coming from my mobile website which is hosted on a subdomain.

mobile app hosted at x.domain.com

laravel app hosted at domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this package - https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors, it still works on Laravel 7 and the documentation is easy to understand.

Besides, why don't you update to the current version? Here is the tutorial - https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade

Comment: I have a mobile static website on a submain. see question edit